¿Como puedo activar el scroll vertilcal dando clic a un elemento?
Estoy creando un archivo el cual contiene varios div, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el primer div esta en  position: fixed ya que es lo primero que va ver el usuario al entrar a la página, por el momento tengo desactivado el scroll, ya que no quiero que el usuario deslice hacia arriba, lo que no he logrado hacer es que al momento de darle clic al checkbox figurando un botón se desactive el scroll y el usuario pueda seguir navegando sin problemas.


$(function() {
        var $body = $(document);
        $body.bind('scroll', function() {
          // "Disable" scroll vertical.
          if ($body.scrollTop() !== 0) {
            $body.scrollTop(0);
          }
        });
      });
.texto1 {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: rgb(134, 5, 151);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   }

   .texto2 p, .texto3 p{
    background-color: rgb(58, 7, 243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }



   .ver{
    background: #917407;
  border: none;
  color: #ffff;
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(95, 89, 89, 0.562), 
  -6px -6px 10px rgba(211, 190, 190, 0.5), 6px 6px 8px rgba(122, 115, 115, 0.616),
   6px 6px 10px rgba(124, 116, 116, 0.548);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
 
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .texto1 {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ver {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollinabiltar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="seccion1">
       <div  class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
         <div id="texto1" class="texto1">
        
         </div>
         <label for="toggle" class="ver">Ver contenido</label>

       </div>
      </div>

    <section id="seccion2">
        <div class="container">
          <dvi class="texto2" id="texto2">
            <h1>Principo de lectura</h1>
            <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
  Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
  ¿Por qué lo usamos?
  
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
  
          </p>
  
          </dvi>
         
        </div>
 
 
     </section>
     <section id="seccion3">
      <div class="container">
        <dvi class="texto3" id="texto3">
          <h1>Seguimiento de lectura</h1>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>

        </dvi>
       
      </div>

   </section>

</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</html>




Solo debes preguntar si el checkbox está activado o no, es decir te falta un if
const $body = $(document);
$body.bind('scroll',function(){
  if(!toggle.checked){
    $body.scrollTop(0)
  }
});

O de forma resumida:
const $body = $(document);
$body.bind('scroll',() => !toggle.checked && $body.scrollTop(0));

Si agregas solo ese código, te darás cuenta de que hay un efecto rebote cuando quitamos el scroll, porque realmente no lo estamos quitando solo lo devolvemos a la posición cero, y el css de Bootstrap agrega el scroll-behavior: smooth, lo que ocasiona el efecto rebote. Entonces, hay que desactivarlo con una regla css
:root:has(#toggle:not(:checked)){
 scroll-behavior: unset !important;
}

Demo:


const $body = $(document);
$body.bind('scroll',() => !toggle.checked && $body.scrollTop(0));
:root:has(#toggle:not(:checked)){
 scroll-behavior: unset !important;
}

.texto1 {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: rgb(134, 5, 151);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   }

   .texto2 p, .texto3 p{
    background-color: rgb(58, 7, 243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }



   .ver{
    background: #917407;
  border: none;
  color: #ffff;
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(95, 89, 89, 0.562), 
  -6px -6px 10px rgba(211, 190, 190, 0.5), 6px 6px 8px rgba(122, 115, 115, 0.616),
   6px 6px 10px rgba(124, 116, 116, 0.548);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
 
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .texto1 {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ver {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollinabiltar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="seccion1">
       <div  class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
         <div id="texto1" class="texto1">
        
         </div>
         <label for="toggle" class="ver">Ver contenido</label>

       </div>
      </div>

    <section id="seccion2">
        <div class="container">
          <dvi class="texto2" id="texto2">
            <h1>Principo de lectura</h1>
            <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
  Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
  ¿Por qué lo usamos?
  
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
  
          </p>
  
          </dvi>
         
        </div>
 
 
     </section>
     <section id="seccion3">
      <div class="container">
        <dvi class="texto3" id="texto3">
          <h1>Seguimiento de lectura</h1>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>

        </dvi>
       
      </div>

   </section>

</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</html>




Adicionalmente, podrás darte cuenta de que empleando la misma técnica utilizada en el css "anti rebote" es igualmente posible quitar el scroll, simplemente haciendo:
:root:has(#toggle:not(:checked)){
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

Sin tener que utilizar javascript


:root:has(#toggle:not(:checked)){
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.texto1 {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: rgb(134, 5, 151);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   }

   .texto2 p, .texto3 p{
    background-color: rgb(58, 7, 243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }



   .ver{
    background: #917407;
  border: none;
  color: #ffff;
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(95, 89, 89, 0.562), 
  -6px -6px 10px rgba(211, 190, 190, 0.5), 6px 6px 8px rgba(122, 115, 115, 0.616),
   6px 6px 10px rgba(124, 116, 116, 0.548);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
 
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .texto1 {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ver {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollinabiltar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="seccion1">
       <div  class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
         <div id="texto1" class="texto1">
        
         </div>
         <label for="toggle" class="ver">Ver contenido</label>

       </div>
      </div>

    <section id="seccion2">
        <div class="container">
          <dvi class="texto2" id="texto2">
            <h1>Principo de lectura</h1>
            <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
 
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
              Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
              ¿Por qué lo usamos?
              
              Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
              Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
  
  Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
  ¿Por qué lo usamos?
  
  Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
  
          </p>
  
          </dvi>
         
        </div>
 
 
     </section>
     <section id="seccion3">
      <div class="container">
        <dvi class="texto3" id="texto3">
          <h1>Seguimiento de lectura</h1>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>

        </dvi>
       
      </div>

   </section>

</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</html>




Tu respuesta también fue de gran de utilidad amigo.

Con CSS es más efectivo. Cuando probaba la versión de JS en el teléfono veía como el contenido se desplazaba un poco hacia abajo y volvía hacia arriba solo

Por supuesto que el scroll sigue estando deshabilitado. Si bien asocias un handler al evento, nunca lo quitas. Para eso, tienes que asociar un nuevo evento para detectar el cambio del checbox y usar unbind. Por cierto, bind y unbind llevan obsoletos desde JQuery 3.0. Considera usar on y off.


let body = $(document)
body.on('scroll', function() {
    // "Disable" scroll vertical
    body.scrollTop(0);
});

$("#cb").change(function () {
    // Quita el evento scroll
    if (this.checked)
        body.off("scroll");
        // body.unbind('scroll');
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">Habilitar scroll</input>
<section>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum dapibus condimentum. Nullam nisi diam, dictum eget aliquam non, suscipit in justo. Sed mattis est vitae est maximus, ut mollis metus condimentum. In id felis consequat, luctus massa ut, venenatis ante. Etiam non ante sed orci finibus ornare a sed massa. Mauris scelerisque sollicitudin erat eget posuere. Quisque scelerisque scelerisque quam vitae semper. Pellentesque commodo in enim sit amet congue. Vivamus tristique nulla a elit egestas, a ullamcorper urna euismod. Nullam pellentesque posuere blandit. Aliquam sit amet dignissim purus, nec pellentesque elit. Nunc molestie porttitor ligula id feugiat. Nunc quis ex at magna lacinia malesuada a in leo.
<br>
Cras viverra at ex sed porta. Pellentesque aliquam aliquam vulputate. Duis bibendum mauris ac pulvinar mollis. Curabitur dictum odio non ipsum lacinia interdum. Quisque nisi lorem, accumsan vel nibh sit amet, posuere sodales diam. Vivamus elementum ligula velit, non auctor augue hendrerit et. Nunc dapibus, est id suscipit euismod, leo sapien gravida velit, nec lobortis mi quam sed quam. Nullam nec dictum augue.
<br>
Proin vitae varius purus, mollis vulputate magna. Sed sed ante non turpis rhoncus luctus. Vestibulum vel lacus volutpat, pulvinar mauris nec, ultricies ipsum. Nulla suscipit, nulla id dapibus fermentum, est nisi lacinia risus, sed convallis nisi enim quis magna. Ut mauris odio, accumsan non quam eget, vulputate finibus magna. Pellentesque enim ipsum, malesuada id neque at, ornare commodo mi. Praesent et ipsum est. Integer dignissim auctor mollis. Praesent vel ultricies nisi. Etiam lorem mauris, blandit quis sapien in, maximus aliquam libero. Aenean condimentum id justo quis tincidunt. Quisque mollis efficitur odio. Integer lacinia vehicula massa, quis ultricies nibh lacinia non.
<br>
Nulla sed ante non ipsum dignissim sagittis nec at metus. Sed vitae neque eros. Quisque in odio eu libero tincidunt consequat at ut ipsum. Integer accumsan lacus sit amet metus cursus, in vulputate eros molestie. Donec lorem nunc, ultricies eget justo sed, fringilla accumsan felis. Nunc nisl massa, ullamcorper id euismod quis, volutpat sit amet nibh. Proin sodales libero nec turpis feugiat, quis pulvinar est facilisis. Integer vehicula, arcu at tempus malesuada, nulla magna imperdiet tellus, ut ultrices lacus purus vel odio. Morbi eu ultrices dui. Donec tempus ullamcorper lorem vel iaculis. Donec vitae nisl ut felis ornare vehicula ut in ligula. Sed malesuada eleifend risus vitae cursus. Sed blandit quam id imperdiet scelerisque. Nullam ac placerat neque.
<br>
Aliquam sollicitudin tellus quis mattis suscipit. Aliquam sollicitudin sollicitudin nulla, ut porta lorem suscipit vitae. Nulla elementum sapien mauris, quis aliquet sem fringilla quis. Nunc dapibus interdum neque et semper. Donec eu lobortis ante, eget scelerisque diam. Donec maximus fermentum sem, a tincidunt purus aliquam a. Sed dapibus purus eget pulvinar hendrerit. Proin rhoncus, ante porttitor porttitor ultricies, libero lacus mattis tellus, ac varius justo quam eu orci.
</section>




Tu respuesta fue de gran utilidad y funciona bien @Mateo, gracias.
